# Bottom vertical align div in parent

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Im having an issue with vertical aligning a button inside of its parent.
The button should be aligned to the bottom of the "info" div but I cannot get it to stick.

I cannot use "position: absolute" in this situation.

And i do not know the height of the main parent div beforehand.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/400" alt="" /></a>
  <div class="info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus rem tenetur temporibus voluptas repellendus.</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 700px; /* The height is variable!!! */
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a { display: block; height: 50%; }
a img { display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }

.info {
  background: #fa0;
  display: block;
  height: calc(50% - 1em);
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.info p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #a0f;
  margin: 0;
}

.info button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: [margin-top: 100%](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/nor1vx0a/). Will this work?

Comment: why can you not use position absolute?

Comment: ^^^ what pete says. http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/o4fj5740/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in some of the comments, position: absolute is the easiest way to do this. However, you said you're restricted on this factor, so here's an alternative using flexbox!

You need to see three properties on the parent element: display, flex-direction, and justify-content. Then put a margin on the child element to make sure its centered at the bottom. Here's an updated fiddle. No absolute position required : ) https://jsfiddle.net/jg8egtb1/

```
.info {
  background: #fa0;
  display: block;
  height: calc(50% - 1em);
  margin-top: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.info button {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D. I was trying something else first and forgot to remove that. Answer edited to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @knolljm! Using flex fixed the issue

Comment: @IvanBuljovčić Glad to hear it. Can you please accept the answer if it has helped you?